# Revoking signature on Laravel temporarysignedroute at the time it accessed

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

So i was searching about sending a link to allow user login by using that, which is sent to their emails. I tried passport but have no idea how to use it after reading its doc for hours. So i have an idea to allow the user login by signedroute, but i want to revoke its signature on the first time it has been accessed like code below. Is that possible? Any suggestion for this login via link is welcomed , desperate af ::))

```
return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
'unsubscribe', whenAccessedfortheFirstTime() , ['user' => 1]);
```

Comment: Passport is really appropriate for this so don't worry if you can't figure out how to use it for this issue. Also you can't do this with `temporarySignedRoute` alone. You could store the temporary signed route in a table and then delete it from the table when it's accessed and not allow access if it's not in that table.

Comment: Checked the source. There's no way to do this by default but what @apokryfos proposed would work. You could check whether a signed route has a valid signature AND if it has not been accessed before.